# How can I use Javascript to access sub-elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

I am dynamically creating forms dynamically according to a users actions. It is an entry-box and a two "buttons" for each instance. Each instance will be wrapped in a unique div tag.

What I tried to do without success is when I dynamically create the "button" I attach a function with the input variable containing the div of its instance. This a brief excerpt:

```
  var newDivClass = document.getElementById("instance"+1);
  button1.innerHTML = "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"buttons("+newDivClass+");\" id=\"button1\"> Button1 </a>";

  function buttons(selected) {
        //I want this to select the first instance 
        //of button1 found within div newDivClass
        selected.getElementById("button1");
        //I also tried
        //this.getElementById("button1");
        //selected.getChildren[0]; 
  }
```

The problem appears to be in passing newDivClass to the the actual function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intent is to pass the name of the object as a string and not a reference to the object itself, then you would need to have enclosing quotes around the newDivClass variable:

```
button1.innerHTML = "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"buttons('"+newDivClass+"');\" id=\"button1\"> Button1 </a>";
```

Otherwise the script in your buttons function will be attempting to operate on an object with the id "instance*n*" at the top level of the dom.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and it passes the object to buttons. However, I still can't access any of the object properties.  alert (selected.hasChildNodes()); for example doesn't work.

Comment: Ah. My changes would only work if you pass the name as a string and then evaluate it internally in the function. Have you tried simply passing buttons(this)? That will pass the newly created div as an argument value.

Answer (score 0):

To get the first child, you can use the `firstChild` property.